# Reform Differential Equation textbooks

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education

I taught Differential Equations once back in 2006, and I am slated to teach it again this Spring.  In 2006, I was assigned used Blanchard, Devaney, Hall, and I really liked this book.  However, I find that it is expensive.

Now I never took Differential Equations myself, and I don't do any kind of applied math.  However, from googling around a bit, I see that this may be what is called "Reform" Differential Equations, and that it emphasizes a qualitative approach. Our SLAC has no engineers, and I suspect that this would serve our students better than Boyce & DiPrima.  (But I have absolutely 0 experience with the traditional approach, so I am going on a hunch).

Does any one here know of other "qualitative" Differential Equations books like Blanchard, Devaney, Hall?  Perhaps even better or less expensive?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps delete here and ask at: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Depending on what sort of "qualitative" view one has in mind, one might like the old book of Hirsch and Smale, or the ODE textbook of V.I. Arnol'd. Since I have no idea what an SLAC is, it's not very clear to me what sort of student you are teaching.

Comment: Sorry, SLAC means Small Liberal Arts College.

Comment: What is the composition of the class?  Where will they go from a Diff Eq class?

Answer (score 0):

"Now I never took Differential Equations myself, and I don't do any kind of applied math."

1. I would just beware of your own blind spots.  Not in math logic, but in pedagogy, application, etc.
2. I would stick with a simple, mechanical approach to the topic.  It is a very large one.  Even the basic techniques can be difficult to over in a semester.  Let alone approximation, computer use, transforms, etc.
3. I would really just show them the main easy manipulative techniques (emphasis on 2nd order constand coefficient diffyQ, homo and nonhomo, that is everywhere in physics, chemistry, and engineering).  Do a very quick, easy touch on the LaPlace transform (no square waves).  Purpose is just an initial exposure.  If they need it more in future, they learn more later.
4. I am partial to the DiffyQ book by Sanchez.  Thin, covers everything, no PDEs.  But if you can't find that, consider Tenenbaum (helps the students wallets).  Skip a lot of the application chapters though.  [I love applications, but there is just not time; plus applications are word problems, thus hard.]  Boyce and DiPrima is OK, but long and expensive.

---

Good luck!